# Is malloc thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, malloc

Is the `malloc()` function re-entrant?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147298/multithreaded-memory-allocators-for-c-c

Comment: Your title and body ask two different things.  Re-entrant normally means "can be safely used in a signal handler", while thread-safe normally means "can be safely used in threads".  It's easier to have thread-safe than re-entrant.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I read somewhere that if you compile with -pthread, malloc becomes thread safe. I´m pretty sure its implementation dependant though, since malloc is ANSI C and threads are not.

If we are talking gcc:

> Compile and link with -pthread and
>   malloc() will be thread-safe, on x86
>   and AMD64.

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c.moderated/browse_thread/thread/2431a99b9bdcef11/ea800579e40f7fa4

Another opinion, more insightful

> {malloc, calloc, realloc, free,
>   posix_memalign} of glibc-2.2+ are
>   thread safe

http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.development.apps/2005-07/0323.html

Comment: "I read somewhere..." is really not the sort of quality befitting an accepted answer.. ;-)

Comment: Whatever he provides the reference links.

Comment: Note that simply adding `-pthreads` does not automatically make malloc thread safe. If you call malloc in a signal handler all sorts of crazy nonsense can happen.

Comment: malloc is not deemed safe to call from a signal handler; very little is. It may work in some contexts, but not legal or portable AFAIK (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Answer (score 111):

Question: "is malloc reentrant"?
Answer: no, it is not. Here is one definition of what makes a routine [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_(subroutine)).

None of the common versions of malloc allow you to re-enter it (e.g. from a signal handler). Note that a reentrant routine may not use locks, and almost all malloc versions in existence do use locks (which makes them thread-safe), or global/static variables (which makes them thread-unsafe *and* non-reentrant).

All the answers so far answer "is malloc thread-safe?", which is an entirely different question. To *that* question the answer is *it depends* on your runtime library, and possibly on the compiler flags you use. On any modern UNIX, you'll get a thread-safe malloc by default. On Windows, use `/MT`, `/MTd`, `/MD` or `/MDd` flags to get thread-safe runtime library.

Comment: Reentrant routines may use locks as long as the lock is reentrant; this necessitates the lock being roughly equivalent to a recursive or error-checking mutex, but with the added stipulation that the single atomic operation that takes the lock must result in the lock structure being in a consistent state for a newly-held lock with a single reference. Of course then you also have to deal with the case where the state protected by the lock has been partially-modified by the interrupted code in the same thread, but nonetheless reentrant locks can be a building block in handling that...

Comment: I believe /MT /MTd /MD etc just means either use release/debug/dynamic or static CRT version, not that malloc is thread safe or not (it actually calls HeapAlloc which has an no serialize optional flag)

Answer (score 17):

This is quite old question and I want to bring freshness according current state of things.

Yes, currently `malloc()` is thread-safe.

From the [GNU C Library Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Basic-Allocation) of `glibc-2.20 [released 2014-09-07]`:

> `void * malloc (size_t size)`
>
> Preliminary: MT-Safe | ...
>
> ...
>   1.2.2.1 POSIX Safety Concepts:
>
> ... MT-Safe or Thread-Safe functions are safe to call in the presence
>   of other threads. MT, in MT-Safe, stands for Multi Thread.
>
> Being MT-Safe does not imply a function is atomic, nor that it uses
>   any of the memory synchronization mechanisms POSIX exposes to users.
>   It is even possible that calling MT-Safe functions in sequence does
>   not yield an MT-Safe combination. For example, having a thread call
>   two MT-Safe functions one right after the other does not guarantee
>   behavior equivalent to atomic execution of a combination of both
>   functions, since concurrent calls in other threads may interfere in a
>   destructive way.
>
> Whole-program optimizations that could inline functions across library
>   interfaces may expose unsafe reordering, and so performing inlining
>   across the GNU C Library interface is not recommended. The documented
>   MT-Safety status is not guaranteed underwhole-program optimization.
>   However, functions defined in user-visible headers are designed to be
>   safe for inlining.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, under [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09) `malloc` is thread-safe.

> 2.9.1 Thread-Safety
>
> All functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall be thread-safe, except that the following functions1 need not be thread-safe.
>
> [ a list of functions that does not contain `malloc` ]

Comment: This is the most relevant answer today. Any modern multithreaded system can safely use malloc().

Answer (score 9):

Here is an excerpt from malloc.c of glibc :

Thread-safety: thread-safe unless NO_THREADS is defined

assuming NO_THREADS is not defined by default, malloc is thread safe at least on linux.

Answer (score 7):

If you are working with GLIBC, the answer is: Yes, BUT.

Specifically, yes, BUT, please, please be aware that while malloc and free are thread-safe, *the debugging functions are not.*

Specifically, the extremely useful mtrace(), mcheck(), and mprobe() functions *are not thread-safe*.  In one of the shortest, straightest answers you will ever see from a GNU project, this is explained here:

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9939

You will need to consider alternate techniques, such as ElectricFence, valgrind, dmalloc, etc.

So, if you mean, "are the malloc() and free() functions threadsafe", the answer is yes.  But if you mean, "is the entire malloc/free *suite* threadsafe", the answer is NO.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: yes, as of C11, which is the first version of the C standard that includes the concept of threads, `malloc` and friends are required to be thread-safe.  Many operating systems that included both threads and a C runtime made this guarantee long before the C standard did, but I'm not prepared to swear to *all*.  However, `malloc` and friends are not and never have been required to be reentrant.

That means, it is safe to call `malloc` and `free` from multiple threads simultaneously and not worry about locking, as long as you aren't breaking any of the other rules of memory allocation (e.g. call `free` once and only once on each pointer returned by `malloc`).  But it is *not* safe to call these functions from a signal handler that might have interrupted a call to `malloc` or `free` in the thread handling the signal.  Sometimes, using functionality beyond ISO C, you can guarantee that the thread handling the signal did not interrupt a call to `malloc` or `free`, e.g. with `sigprocmask` and `sigpause`, but try not to do that unless you have no other option, because it's hard to get perfectly right.

---

Long answer with citations: The C standard added a concept of threads in the [2011 revision](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html) (link is to document N1570, which is the closest approximation to the official text of the 2011 standard that is publicly available at no charge).  In that revision, [section 7.1.4 paragraph 5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p5) states:

> Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow, library functions shall prevent data races as follows: A library function shall not directly or indirectly access objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's arguments. A library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's non-const arguments. Implementations may share their own internal objects between threads if the objects are not visible to users and are protected against data races.
>
> [footnote: This means, for example, that an implementation is not permitted to use a static object for internal purposes without synchronization because it could cause a data race even in programs that do not explicitly share objects between threads. Similarly, an implementation of memcpy is not permitted to copy bytes beyond the specified length of the destination object and then restore the original values because it could cause a data race if the program shared those bytes between threads.]

As I understand it, this is a long-winded way of saying that the library functions defined by the C standard are required to be thread-safe (in the usual sense: you can call them from multiple threads simultaneously, without doing any locking yourself, as long as they don't end up clashing on the data passed as arguments) unless the documentation for a specific function specifically says it isn't.

Then, [7.22.3p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3p2) confirms that malloc, calloc, realloc, aligned_alloc, and free in particular are thread-safe:

> For purposes of determining the existence of a data race, memory allocation functions behave as though they accessed only memory locations accessible through their arguments and not other static duration storage. These functions may, however, visibly modify the storage that they allocate or deallocate. A call to free or realloc that deallocates a region p of memory synchronizes with any allocation call that allocates all or part of the region p. This synchronization occurs after any access of p by the deallocating function, and before any such access by the allocating function.

Contrast what it says about strtok, which is not and never has been thread-safe, in [7.24.5.8p6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8p6):

> The strtok function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to the strtok function.
>
> [footnote: The strtok_s function can be used instead to avoid data races.]

(comment on the footnote: don't use `strtok_s`, use `strsep`.)

Older versions of the C standard said nothing whatsoever about thread safety.  However, they *did* say something about reentrancy, because signals have always been part of the C standard.  And this is what they said, going back to the original [1989 ANSI C standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20151125170555/http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) (this document has nigh-identical wording to, but very different section numbering from, the ISO C standard that came out the following year):

> If [a] signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort
> or raise function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler
> calls any function in the standard library other than the signal
> function itself or refers to any object with static storage duration
> other than by assigning a value to a static storage duration variable
> of type volatile sig_atomic_t .  Furthermore, if such a call to the
> signal function results in a SIG_ERR return, the value of errno is
> indeterminate.

Which is a long-winded way of saying that C library functions are *not* required to be reentrant as a general rule.  Very similar wording still appears in C11, [7.14.1.1p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p5):

> If [a] signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or raise function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than the abort function, the _Exit function, the quick_exit function, or the signal function with the first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler. Furthermore, if such a call to the signal function results in a SIG_ERR return, the value of errno is indeterminate.
>
> [footnote: If any signal is generated by an asynchronous signal handler, the behavior is undefined.]

POSIX requires a [much longer, but still short compared to the overall size of the C library](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), list of functions to be safely callable from an "asynchronous signal handler", and also defines in more detail the circumstances under which a signal might "occur other than as the result of calling the abort or raise function."  If you're doing anything nontrivial with signals, you are probably writing code intended to be run on an OS with the Unix nature (as opposed to Windows, MVS, or something embedded that probably doesn't have a complete hosted implementation of C in the first place), and you should familiarize yourself with the POSIX requirements for them, as well as the ISO C requirements.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest reading

> §31.1 Thread Safety (and Reentrancy Revisited)

of the book *The Linux Programming Interface*, it explains the difference between thread safety and reentrancy, as well as `malloc`.

Excerpt：

> A function is said to be thread-safe if it can safely be invoked by
>   multiple threads at the same time; put conversely, if a function is
>   not thread-safe, then we can’t call it from one thread while it is
>   being executed in another thread.
>
> ....
>    This function illustrates the typical reason that a function is not
>   thread-safe: it employs global or static variables that are shared by all threads.
>
> ...
>   Although the use of critical sections to implement thread safety is a significant
>   improvement over the use of per-function mutexes, it is still somewhat inefficient
>   because there is a cost to locking and unlocking a mutex. A reentrant function
>   achieves thread safety without the use of mutexes. It does this by avoiding the use
>   of global and static variables.
>
> ...
>   However, not all functions can
>   be made reentrant. The usual reasons are the following:
>
> - By their nature, some functions must access global data structures. The functions in the malloc library provide a good example. These functions maintain a
>     global linked list of free blocks on the heap. The functions of the `malloc` library
>     are made thread-safe through the use of mutexes.
>
> ....

Definitely worth a read.

And to answer your question, `malloc` is thread safe but not reentrant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which implementation of the C runtime library you're using. If you're using MSVC for example then there's a compiler option which lets you specify which version of the library you want to build with (i.e. a run-time library that supports multi-threading by being tread-safe, or not).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not thread-safe. There may actually be a `malloc_lock()` and `malloc_unlock()` function available in your C library. I know that these exist for the Newlib library. I had to use this to implement a mutex for my processor, which is multi-threaded in hardware.

Comment: Any implementation of malloc on any system conforming to any major threads standard (such as POSIX) is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

malloc and free are not reentrant, because they use a static data structure which records what memory blocks are free. As a result, no library functions that allocate or free memory are reentrant.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

[Web archive link (original has gone dead)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100501162929/http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2007-07/msg02658.html)

Comment: As stated at http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c.moderated/browse_thread/thread/2431a99b9bdcef11/ea800579e40f7fa4, this is not strictly correct.  malloc is neither guaranteed to be, nor guaranteed not be, thread-safe.  It is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Safety is not partial; if an implementation may not be safe, my interpretation is that it is not safe.  Poster did not specify a platform; therefore, no guarantee of safety can be given.

Comment: Any given implementation either is or isn't safe. To say that an unknown implementation is unsafe is no more true than saying that it is safe. The correct answer is that it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @ChrisW: since the OP did not specify the implementation, and since safety is an absolute condition (it can be broken with only one exception; only one unsafe action can make something "unsafe"), I decided to answer that it was unsafe.  The original poster can determine for him/her self what is the correct answer.

Comment: @ChrisW - Russian roulette is safe.

Comment: @PaulSonier Link is broken, link-only answer, not a good combo.