# Are memmove and malloc thread safe?

Tags: c

I have some code that moves bytes in a buffer using `memmove()`. The buffer is accessed by multiple threads. I get a very weird behavior; sometimes the buffer it's not what it should be and I was thinking if `memmove()` or/and `malloc()` are thread safe. I'm working on iOS (in case this is platform dependent).

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: Internets +1: I googled your question and StackOverflow came up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/malloc-thread-safe

Comment: Indeed, but still, I was not sure about `memmove()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an implementation that provides threads, `malloc` will normally be thread safe (i.e., it will take steps to assure the heap doesn't get corrupted, even if `malloc` gets called from multiple threads). The exact way it will do that varies: some use a single heap, and internal synchronization to ensure against corruption. Others will use multiple heaps, so different threads can allocate memory simultaneously without collisions.

`memmove` will normally be just like if you did assignments in your own code -- if you're sharing a buffer across threads, it's your responsibility to synchronize access to that data.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a mutex ([NSLock](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSLock)) as a protective barrier around accessing your buffer.  Take a look at [Synchronization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) in Apple's [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Multithreading.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Malloc may be thread-safe.  The standard doesn't require it, but many C compilers are used in systems whose applications requires thread safety, and your particular compiler's library may be thread safe, or offer a thread safe option.  I don't know about iOS.

Memmove (or any other kind of block move) is not thread safe, any more than an assignment statement is thread safe.

Comment: Every threading specification for C I've ever seen requires `malloc` to be thread-safe, and of course the upcoming C1x standard will. `memmove` is also thread-safe in the normal definition of thread-safe, which excludes using it to modify the same object from multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: @R: Every? The compiler vendor does something, and yes it is popular but it isn't a requirement. MSVS's malloc isn't thread safe unless you pick the right library. I thought I was clear about memmove being the same as assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Since the current C standard does not specify threads, it has nothing to say about thread safety. Whenever you have threads, you're dealing with a system that has placed further requirements, beyond the basic C language standard's requirements, on how the standard library functions behave. I'm not sure what requirements iOS makes, but POSIX and Windows both require `malloc` to be thread-safe, and I'd find it hard to believe any system designed after the mid 90s would not make this requirement.

Note that the upcoming C1x standard will specify threads, and if the implementation has threads, then `malloc` will be required to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

No, since the standard C library doesn't have a concept of threads, the functions it defines can't be.

Comment: I see, so basically NO functions are thread safe in C (standard)? Good to know! I think this IS my problem then!

Comment: @mindnoise: the C standard isn't thread-aware, but since most of the current CRT implementations are used in multithreaded environments, each specific compiler usually gives particular guaranties about what is and what isn't thread-safe in the standard library.

Comment: OK, that means that I have to find out if in Objective-C/iOS they are or not, although judging after the comments, I think not.

Comment: Functions that don't operate on some kind of shared static (non-stack) state might be safe, stuff like strtol() for instance.

Comment: @unwind - even then you can't rely on it unless the vendor says they are. Even strtol has internal state as it parses the string.

Comment: @Martin: of course it has state, but I would expect that to be on the stack, so two threads running the same code would have no data in common. That's what I meant, I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @unwind - almost certainly true. But subtle are the ways of compiler and library writers - you can't trust em!