# malloc() is non-reentrant but thread-safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, malloc, reentrancy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Malloc thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/malloc-thread-safe)

I am not a bit confused while I am reading "The Linux Programming Interface".

From the book it says that malloc is non-reentrant since it manipulates the global linked list data structure but is made thread-safe by using mutex.

I am a bit confused about this: since it's thread-safe with using mutex and thus can be invoked by more than one threads at the same time, why it isn't a reentrant function? (if we say that reentrant means that it can be invoked by more than one caller at the same time)

Another question is that, since malloc is thread-safe, can we put it in a signal handler?
I think the answer is yes but I am not sure since according to this book, it says that only a reentrant or async-signal-safe function can be put in the signal handler.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Is the mutex included in malloc's implementation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> if we say that reentrant means that it can be invoked by more than one
>   caller at the same time

Wrong. Reentrant means **you can interrupt it and call it again before the previous incarnation ended**. Imagine malloc looks like this:

```
lock(mutex);

/* Stuff. */

unlock(mutex):
```

What happens if it is interrupted in the middle, **before unlocking** and someone else calls `malloc` ?

- The first context cannot continue until the second one is done
- The second context blocks on the mutex and cannot continue until the first unlocks the mutex

That's a deadlock.

> Another question is that, since malloc is thread-safe, can we put it
>   in a signal handler? I think the answer is yes

Wrong again. See the example above. Imagine the main program is doing a `malloc` and before the function actually ends your handler calls malloc.

Comment: Thanks cnicutar, the answer is VERY CLEAR!!

Comment: @kai: Note that the problem (confusing these concepts) is exacerbated by the fact that older versions of POSIX (pre-2008) wrongly used the word reentrant to mean thread-safe...

Answer (score 2):

Reentrancy and thread-safety are two different concepts. A reentrant function can be non-thread -safe and a thread-safe function can be non-reentrant.

Library functions in C are not guaranteed to be reentrant and only reentrant functions can be called from signal handlers.

Comment: `A reentrant function can be non-thread-safe` ... Can it?

Comment: @iuliux: Yes.  On some machines, static variables are faster than stack-based local variables.  Code which on entry copies its static variables to the stack, uses the static variables, and then restores the variables from the stack will be re-entrant but not thread-safe.