# Is there any possibility of Memory corruption or segment fault?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, segmentation-fault, memory-corruption

Suppose I am having the following C function

```
void *AllocateMemory(int numBytes)
{

     //allocate "numBytes" of memory

     //return the memory address
}
```

if the above function is accessed by so many process say like 100 PARALLELY, is there any possibility of Memory corruption or segment fault?

Note: Environment is multithreading.

Comment: It very much depends on the implementation of that function. If it uses proper locking then all is fine. `malloc(3)` locks it's structures for each call.

Comment: no locking is there..just a plain allocation

Comment: How is the allocation done? I can't tell you if your function is thread-safe without source code.

Comment: Post full definition of the function. It would only be speculative to comment without it.

Comment: When it's multiple threads in a single process, the mechanisms involved are those of your C library implementation, so beware if it's not a widely-used one. When it's multiple processes, the mechanisms involved are those of the OS kernel, so there's little to no risk if you're running on a mainstream OS or linux distro.

Comment: That sounds exactly like `malloc()`. And `malloc()` is multithreading safe on any sane system.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse processes and threads.

With processes, nothing can happen at all.

With threads, if your function works straightforward and doesn't touch or use any shared resources, it should work as well.

Comment: Ty for responding.
Yes the allocation is straight forward. i.e

void *allocateMem()
{
     //allocate Mem
     //No Locking-Shocking uis there in between
     //retuen Mem
}

Still i am comfused how com a assure myself that there will be no cprruption???

Comment: Just **HOW** are you allocating the mem? By calling malloc()?

Comment: OKAI LET SAY LIKE thIS:

void *AllocateMem(int numBytes) {  return (malloc(numBytes));  }

If this func is acessed by like 100 or 1000 process which are craving for memory what will happen??  Is there any possiblity of Memory corruption or segment fault?

Comment: No such possibility if you're using a "mainstream enough" OS. Just make sure processes don't try to use the null pointer when an allocation fails.

Comment: Theres no problem with malloc cos here in my envronment..memory is plenty so  every malloc call will be success...just curious if such parallel execution of code will lead to memory corruption or not????
As i have to transfer this code to a production quality code for a product

Comment: Again: if it is done by several processes, their address area is distinct from each other, so nothing can happen.

Answer (score 1):

All processes have their own address space, so multiple processes are not a problem.

For threading, the answer is that it depends on your `malloc()` implementation.

Most common implementations I have come across are thread safe.  See this question for more info

[Is malloc thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/malloc-thread-safe)