# Is `asprintf` thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, printf, glibc, asprintf

Is the GNU function `asprintf` (print to allocated string) thread-safe?

(IIC, basically, this boils down to the question whether `malloc` is thread-safe.)

Consider the example code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

#include "getValue.h"

char * getValue(int key) {
  char * value;
  asprintf(&value, "%d", key); // TODO: No error handling!
  // If memory allocation wasn't possible, or some other error occurs,  these  functions  will
  // return -1, and the contents of strp is undefined.
  return value;
}
```

Here, I do not touch any global variables. What if my `getValue` gets called in concurrent threads? No bad things will occur, will they?

Comment: Users would be doomed if malloc weren't thread-safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/is-malloc-thread-safe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's thread safe except when it reads the locale.

[asprintf](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Output.html#Dynamic-Output)

> Function: int asprintf (char **ptr, const char *template, …)
>   Preliminary: | MT-Safe locale | AS-Unsafe heap | AC-Unsafe mem

About the 'locale' [exception](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Other-Safety-Remarks.html#Other-Safety-Remarks), in particular:

> Functions annotated with locale as an MT-Safety issue read from the locale object without any form of synchronization. Functions annotated with locale called concurrently with locale changes may behave in ways that do not correspond to any of the locales active during their execution, but an unpredictable mix thereof.

These kinds of functions are known as ["conditionally"](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Conditionally-Safe-Features.html#Conditionally-Safe-Features) multithread safe because, in some contexts, they turn out not to be, so the programmer needs to take care of that.

Comment: I've just looked at the referenced [POSIX Safety Concepts](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX-Safety-Concepts.html#POSIX-Safety-Concepts), and there is no hint about the locale exception. So, for me to able to read these lines like the "Preliminary: ..." above, I need additionally to understand the meaning of the modifiers like "locale", "heap", "mem". Where can I look up those?

Comment: Some platforms offer `asprintf_l` which takes a `locale_t` parameter and should be completely thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

[glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) and is probably the only (or the most important) library implementing `asprintf`.

So you can study (and even [contribute](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Contribution%20checklist) to improve) its source code.  See its [stdio-common/asprintf.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/asprintf.c;hb=HEAD) & [libio/vasprintf.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/vasprintf.c;hb=HEAD) source files.

It looks like indeed, it is calling in a thread safe manner `malloc` and related things.

Comment: is that K&R function parameter style?

Comment: Yes for `_IO_vasprintf`

Comment: Any particular reason why that is used in glib ... in 2015?

Comment: Because nobody cared to send a patch for the transition to C99. If you care, please fill the legal papers and propose the patch. See [glibc contribution checklist](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Contribution%20checklist)