# Mixed project C and C++ using pthreads

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex, new-operator

I've a mixed project with a huge ammount of old C code and some C++ code as a wrapper linked together in a single binary.

The C code uses a mutex to make `malloc`-memory-management thread safe, the C++ part does not care pthreads. Will the usage of `malloc` together with `new` be thread-safe, if these are true:

- `malloc`, `realloc` and `free` are protected by a mutex.
- The standard `new`-operator is used (I think, it's a pthread-enabled version by default, if pthreads are used, right?)
- Memory allocated by `malloc` is never freed by `delete` and vice-versa.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/855763/3684343

Comment: Are you targeting full posix cross-platform compatibility? Or just, say, Linux with gcc? Which C and C++ Standards are you targeting (the answer is trivial with the latest versions, assuming conforming compilers).

Comment: @BoBTFish: Linux and gcc only

Comment: @urzeit Then I believe with `-pthread` you are fine, but I'll let someone else fill in the details/provide references (or contradict me of course).

Comment: [This](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html#NOTES) reports `malloc` is safe, but didn't find a reference that `new` is implemented in terms of `malloc`, although several SO answers state this without a reference.

Comment: I thought malloc was threadsafe if you #defined something.  Can't recall what.