# MALLOC_CHECK Multithreaded or not?

Tags: c, malloc

I am working on a multithreaded C application. Recently we observed some memory corruptions(very rare) . To identify that we were tested with -lmcheck linking . But after we came to know that -lmcheck is not thread safe. Then we start testing with MALLOC_CHECK=3 . Here I have a unsolved doubt I.e. -lmcheck and MALLOC_CHECK=3 behaviour same or not ? MALLOC_CHECK=3 thread safe or not ? If any one answers this it very helpful for me .. I tried with valgrind , electric fence but no use.

Answer (score 1):

As per the GNU article on Heap consistency Checking mcheck is defined as MT-Unsafe.

> Function: int mcheck (void (*abortfn) (enum mcheck_status status))
>
> Preliminary: | **MT-Unsafe** race:mcheck const:malloc_hooks | AS-Unsafe
> corrupt | AC-Unsafe corrupt
>
> **MT-Unsafe, AS-Unsafe, AC-Unsafe** functions are not safe to call within
> the safety contexts described above. Calling them within such contexts
> invokes undefined behavior.

**So, what’s the difference between using MALLOC_CHECK_ and linking with ‘-lmcheck’?**

> MALLOC_CHECK_ is independent with respect to ‘-lmcheck’.
> ‘-lmcheck’ has been added for backward compatibility. Both
> MALLOC_CHECK_ and ‘-lmcheck’ should uncover the same bugs - but using
> MALLOC_CHECK_ you don’t need to recompile your application.

**Setting MALLOC_CHECK_ :**

> If MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 0 (zero), the memory management functions
> are simply most tolerant of errors and do not give warnings. Maybe be
> useful if we are prevented from finding one memory bug by another that
> is not convenient to fix at the moment; it might allow us to use other
> tools to chase down the other memory bug. It may also be useful if you
> are running code that works on another system but not on Linux.  It
> can provide a quick workaround that may allow the code to temporarily
> function, before you have the chance to resolve the error.
>
> If MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 1 (one), the memory management functions
> print out warning messages on standard error when problems are
> noticed. It is useful if we are not aware of any problems and just
> want to be notified if any problem exist.
>
> If MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 2 (two), the memory management functions
> call abort()when problems are noticed. This is most useful from inside
> the debugger or a shell starting an application or daemon.  It allows
> a backtrace to be obtained as soon as the memory management functions
> discover an error, providing information closest to the point at which
> the error has happened. If a core is caused by a memory corruption, we
> have more information about memory allocations.  This is better for
> troubleshooting and determining where/which application overwrote a
> memory address.
>
> Settings 1 and 2 can be combined by setting MALLOC_CHECK_ to 3
> (three).  This will enable the print out of warning messages on
> standard error (1), and will call abort() when problems are noticed
> (2).

For more information please go through this link for better understanding:
[Heap Consistency Checking](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html#Heap-Consistency-Checking)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use the `MALLOC_CHECK_` (note trailing underscore) approach without linking an external library, it seems reasonable to conclude that it engages a different implementation than libmcheck does.  In any case, the two are both GNU extensions, documented as alternatives.

I suppose what you really want to know is whether using `MALLOC_CHECK_` breaks thread safety of dynamic memory allocation.  Glibc specifies that its `malloc()` implementation is thread safe (see for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27047048/2402272), as indeed POSIX requires.  It is conceivable that its thread safety is broken by non-zero values of `MALLOC_CHECK_`, but that seems unlikely, and I find no documentation of such.