# TeamSpeak 3 program stopped working after add own plugin

Tags: c, asynchronous, plugins, teamspeak

I've made a ts3 plugin this is code:

```
int ts3plugin_onTextMessageEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID targetMode, anyID toID, anyID fromID, const char* fromName, const char* fromUniqueIdentifier, const char* message, int ffIgnored) {
    if(ffIgnored) {
        return 0; /* Client will ignore the message anyways, so return value here doesn't matter */
    }

    /* Example code: Autoreply to sender */
    /* Disabled because quite annoying, but should give you some ideas what is possible here */
    /* Careful, when two clients use this, they will get banned quickly... */
    anyID myID;
    if(ts3Functions.getClientID(serverConnectionHandlerID, &myID) != ERROR_ok) {
        ts3Functions.logMessage("Error querying own client id", LogLevel_ERROR, "Plugin", serverConnectionHandlerID);
        return 0;
    }


    printf("start plugin music");
    HANDLE hStdout;

    TCHAR msgBuf[255];
    msgBuf[0] = "a";
    size_t cchStringSize;
    DWORD dwChars;

    // Make sure there is a console to receive output results. 

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 1;
    if(targetMode == TextMessageTarget_CHANNEL) {
        if(fromID != myID && serverConnectionHandlerID != 1) {  /* Don't reply when source is own client */
            char *str3 = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(message) + 1 + strlen(fromUniqueIdentifier));
            strcpy(str3, message);
            strcat(str3, " ");
            strcat(str3, fromUniqueIdentifier);
            if(checkMessage(str3, serverConnectionHandlerID, toID, fromID)) {
                printf("true");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;  /* 0 = handle normally, 1 = client will ignore the text message */
}

// Sample custom data structure for threads to use.
// This is passed by void pointer so it can be any data type
// that can be passed using a single void pointer (LPVOID).
typedef struct MyData {
    uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID;
    anyID toID;
    anyID fromID;
} MYDATA, *PMYDATA;

BOOL checkMessage(const char *message, uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID toID, anyID fromID) {
    const char *init = "#pj ";

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(init); i++) {
        if(message[i] != init[i])
            return FALSE;
    }

    writeToFile(message, "file.txt");

    PMYDATA pData;
    DWORD   dwThreadId;
    HANDLE  hThread;

    pData = (PMYDATA)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(MYDATA));

    if(pData == NULL) {
        // If the array allocation fails, the system is out of memory
        // so there is no point in trying to print an error message.
        // Just terminate execution.
        ExitProcess(2);
    }

    pData->serverConnectionHandlerID = serverConnectionHandlerID;
    pData->toID = toID;
    pData->fromID = fromID;

    hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        MyThreadFunction,       // thread function name
        pData,          // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadId);   // returns the thread identifier

    //WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    return FALSE;
}

void writeToFile(char *comm, char *file) {
    FILE *fp;
    char *str1 = "some/path/";
    char *str3 = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(str1) + strlen(file));
    strcpy(str3, str1);
    strcat(str3, file);
    fp = fopen(str3, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", comm);
    fclose(fp);
    free(str3);
}

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) {
    PMYDATA pDataArray;

    // Cast the parameter to the correct data type.
    // The pointer is known to be valid because 
    // it was checked for NULL before the thread was created.

    pDataArray = (PMYDATA)lpParam;
    FILE *fp;
    long lSize;
    const char *buffer;

    fp = fopen("some/path/file2.txt", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(fp);
    if(lSize > 0) {
        const char *priv = "$";
        int priv_length = 1;
        rewind(fp);

        buffer = calloc(1, lSize + 1);
        fread(buffer, lSize, 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);

        fp = fopen("some/path/file2.txt", "w");
        fclose(fp);

        if(buffer[0] == priv[0]) {
            const char *buffer2;
            buffer2 = calloc(1, lSize);
            strncpy(buffer2, buffer + 1, lSize - 1);
            ts3Functions.requestSendPrivateTextMsg(pDataArray->serverConnectionHandlerID, buffer2, pDataArray->fromID, NULL);
            free(buffer2);
        } else
            ts3Functions.requestSendChannelTextMsg(pDataArray->serverConnectionHandlerID, buffer, pDataArray->toID, NULL);

        free(buffer);
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    MyThreadFunction(lpParam);
}
```

The problem is that (when i have turn on my plugin) after few minutes of running ts3 it stops working. It must be something wrong with creating thread, because before i've added code from here [Creating Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx) everything was fine, but now i need checking if file was changed.

Comment: Is this question relevant: [Is malloc thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/is-malloc-thread-safe)

Comment: I used malloc in this plugin before i've added new thread and it was working fine.

Comment: Yes, but now you have it in `MyThreadFunction` (well `calloc` which follows `malloc`).

Comment: How can i replace calloc function?

Comment: Allocate memory for the thread before you start it, pass it to the thread.

Comment: But i want to read file if it has been changed. It can be different size.