# How to know which malloc is used?

Tags: c++, malloc, heap-memory

The way I understand it, there exist many different malloc implementations:

- dlmalloc – General purpose allocator
- ptmalloc2 – glibc
- jemalloc – FreeBSD and Firefox
- tcmalloc – Google
- libumem – Solaris

Is there any way to determine which malloc is actually used on my (linux) system?

I read that "due to ptmalloc2’s threading support, it became the default memory allocator for linux." Is there any way for me to check this myself?

I am asking because I do not seem to get any speed up by paralellizing my malloc loop in the code below:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i += 1 ) {
    parallelMalloc(i);
}

 void parallelMalloc(int parallelism, int mallocCnt = 10000000) {

    omp_set_num_threads(parallelism);

    std::vector<char*> ptrStore(mallocCnt);

    boost::posix_time::ptime t1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < mallocCnt; i++) {
        ptrStore[i] = ((char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char)));
    }

    boost::posix_time::ptime t2 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < mallocCnt; i++) {
        free(ptrStore[i]);
    }

    boost::posix_time::ptime t3 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();


    boost::posix_time::time_duration malloc_time = t2 - t1;
    boost::posix_time::time_duration free_time   = t3 - t2;

    std::cout << " parallelism = "  << parallelism << "\t itr = " << mallocCnt <<  "\t malloc_time = " <<
            malloc_time.total_milliseconds() << "\t free_time = " << free_time.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;
}
```

which gives me an output of

```
 parallelism = 1         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1225      free_time = 1517
 parallelism = 2         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1614      free_time = 1112
 parallelism = 3         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1619      free_time = 687
 parallelism = 4         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 2325      free_time = 620
 parallelism = 5         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 2233      free_time = 550
 parallelism = 6         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 2207      free_time = 489
 parallelism = 7         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 2778      free_time = 398
 parallelism = 8         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1813      free_time = 389
 parallelism = 9         itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1997      free_time = 350
 parallelism = 10        itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1922      free_time = 291
 parallelism = 11        itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 2480      free_time = 257
 parallelism = 12        itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1614      free_time = 256
 parallelism = 13        itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1387      free_time = 289
 parallelism = 14        itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1481      free_time = 248
 parallelism = 15        itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1252      free_time = 297
 parallelism = 16        itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 1063      free_time = 281
```

Comment: It depends on which library (libraries) you link with.  The default will probably be the one in glibc — you'd have to work to ensure that you're using another version.  Also, C++ uses `new` and `delete` (and variants); they're not necessarily tied to `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: XY problem? Why do you care?

Comment: @SergeyA I care because I would like to make sure that I use a malloc which supports multithreading w.r.t. performance.

Comment: In essence, all versions will have to support multithreading because modern systems are multithreaded.  Until you identify a problem, you probably shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks, but I am worried because adding more threads does slow down my code, which does a lot of heap allocations. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504223/malloc-performance-in-a-multithreaded-enviroment

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  care because I would like to make sure that I use a malloc which supports multithreading w.r.t. performance

Comment: You should profile your code to determine where exactly the bottleneck is before you start trying to swap out the allocator

Comment: @ Captain Obvlious

well my code is 

 #pragma omp parallel for
 for (int i = 0; i < mallocCnt; i++) {
  ptrStore[i] = ((char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char)));
 }
And I vary the omp_set_num_threads(parallelism); with 0 < parallelism < 16.

Comment: @user695652:  Please look at your comment.  Is the code readable?  Please **edit** your question with code.  The code will look more readable in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read that "due to ptmalloc2’s threading support, it became the default memory allocator for linux." Is there any way for me to check this myself?

`glibc` internally uses `ptmalloc2` and this isn't a recent development. Either way, it's not terribly difficult to do `getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION`, then cross-check the version to see if `ptmalloc2` is used in that version or not, but I'm willing to bet you'd be wasting your time.

> I am asking because I do not seem to get any speed up by paralellizing my malloc loop in the code below

Turning your example into an [MVCE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5acfcc8825aaf79f) (omitting code here for brevity), and compiling with `g++ -Wall -pedantic -O3 -pthread -fopenmp`, with `g++ 5.3.1` here are my results.

With OpenMP:

```
 parallelism = 1     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 746   free_time = 263
 parallelism = 2     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 541   free_time = 267
 parallelism = 3     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 405   free_time = 259
 parallelism = 4     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 324   free_time = 221
 parallelism = 5     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 330   free_time = 242
 parallelism = 6     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 287   free_time = 244
 parallelism = 7     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 257   free_time = 226
 parallelism = 8     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 270   free_time = 225
 parallelism = 9     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 253   free_time = 225
 parallelism = 10    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 236   free_time = 226
 parallelism = 11    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 225   free_time = 239
 parallelism = 12    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 276   free_time = 258
 parallelism = 13    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 241   free_time = 228
 parallelism = 14    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 254   free_time = 225
 parallelism = 15    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 278   free_time = 272
 parallelism = 16    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 235   free_time = 220

23.87 user 
2.11 system 
0:10.41 elapsed 
249% CPU
```

Without OpenMP:

```
 parallelism = 1     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 748   free_time = 263
 parallelism = 2     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 344   free_time = 256
 parallelism = 3     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 751   free_time = 254
 parallelism = 4     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 339   free_time = 262
 parallelism = 5     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 748   free_time = 253
 parallelism = 6     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 330   free_time = 256
 parallelism = 7     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 734   free_time = 260
 parallelism = 8     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 334   free_time = 259
 parallelism = 9     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 750   free_time = 256
 parallelism = 10    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 339   free_time = 255
 parallelism = 11    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 743   free_time = 267
 parallelism = 12    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 342   free_time = 261
 parallelism = 13    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 739   free_time = 252
 parallelism = 14    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 333   free_time = 252
 parallelism = 15    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 740   free_time = 252
 parallelism = 16    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 330   free_time = 252

13.38 user 
4.66 system 
0:18.08 elapsed 
99% CPU
```

Parallelism seems to be faster by about 8 seconds. Still not convinced? OK. I went ahead and grabbed [`dlmalloc`](https://github.com/ennorehling/dlmalloc), ran `make` to produce `libmalloc.a`. My new command like is `g++ -Wall -pedantic -O3 -pthread -fopenmp -L$HOME/Development/test/dlmalloc/lib test.cpp -lmalloc`

With OpenMP:

```
parallelism = 1  itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 814   free_time = 277
```

I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>'d after 37 seconds.

Without OpenMP:

```
 parallelism = 1     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 772   free_time = 271
 parallelism = 2     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 780   free_time = 272
 parallelism = 3     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 783   free_time = 272
 parallelism = 4     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 792   free_time = 277
 parallelism = 5     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 813   free_time = 281
 parallelism = 6     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 800   free_time = 275
 parallelism = 7     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 795   free_time = 277
 parallelism = 8     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 790   free_time = 273
 parallelism = 9     itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 788   free_time = 277
 parallelism = 10    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 784   free_time = 276
 parallelism = 11    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 786   free_time = 284
 parallelism = 12    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 807   free_time = 279
 parallelism = 13    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 791   free_time = 277
 parallelism = 14    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 790   free_time = 273
 parallelism = 15    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 785   free_time = 276
 parallelism = 16    itr = 10000000  malloc_time = 787   free_time = 275

6.48 user 
11.27 system 
0:17.81 elapsed 
99% CPU
```

Pretty significant difference. I suspect that the issue lies within your more complicated code, or something's wrong with your benchmark.