# malloc / new lock and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

How should I use `new`  in a multithread environment?

Precisely: I have a piece of code that I run with 40 threads. Each thread invokes `new` a few times. I noticed that performance drops, probably because threads lock in `new` (significant time is spent in `__lll_lock_wait_parallel` and `__lll_unlock_wait_parallel`). What is the best alternative to `new` / `delete` I can use?

Related:

- http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/multiproc/multiproc.html
- [Is malloc thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/malloc-thread-safe)

Comment: Is this C or C++? malloc is for C, new for C++.

Comment: C++, thanks. Yes, I use new, not malloc. Just edited question

Comment: _probably_ due to locks? Tests from even several years ago even indicate that GCC manages no loss in performance for allocation from multiple threads (that is, total time is linear with the allocations, not with the threads).

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: thanks, thats a good hint. _locks_ was my best shot - maybe there is other cause.. But, you have other `malloc`s (see Will's answer), so there _is_ an issue of multithread malloc..

Comment: In additon to @Will's answer, here is a good list of [Multithreaded Memory Allocators for C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/147298/425817)

Answer (score 6):

Even if you are using the `new` operator, its using `malloc` underneath to do the allocation and deallocation.  The focus should be on the allocator and not the API used to reach it in these circumstances.

***[TCMalloc](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html)*** is a malloc created at Google specifically for good performance in a multi-threading environment.  It is part of [google-perf-tools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/).

Another malloc you might look at is ***[Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/)***.  It has much the same aims as TCMalloc.

Comment: Is it really true that new uses malloc underneath?

Comment: @user695652 it usually does.

Comment: All of the Google links are death. Could you update them?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about "the best", but I would try a few things:

- Reduce the frequency of allocations / frees (might be hard). Just waste memory (but don't leak) if it improves performance
- Roll my own, per-thread allocator and always alloc / free from the same thread using `mmap`  for the real memory

To roll your own primitive allocator:

- Use `mmap` to obtain a large chunk of memory from the OS
- Use a data structure (linked list, tree etc) to keep track of free and used blocks
- Never free data allocated by another thread

I don't consider this trivial to do but if done right it could improve performance. The hairiest part is by far keeping track of the allocations, preventing fragmentation etc.

A simple implementation is provided in "*The C Programming Language*", near the end of the book (but it uses `brk` IIRC).

Comment: Could you elaborate the second point, about "per-thread allocator"?

Comment: @downvoter I really love it when you downvote and don't comment.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think this a good solution to recommend.  At the detail level, mmap is for mapping files; if you want to reserve a large address range use malloc to get memory for your custom allocator.  Also it doesn't play well with new and delete.  Thirdly its a linear allocator.  On consideration, bad advice.

Comment: @Will I can agree with the `new` part (my solution is constructor oblivious). But you are aware some `malloc` implementations call `mmap`, right ? (I think the `jemalloc` does this and other BSD's too). **`mmap` can be used to reserve memory**. In any case, I cave *no problem whatsoever* with the downvote if it's accompanied by a comment. BTW, what do you mean by me suggesting a "linear allocator" ?

Comment: @cnicutar yes I'm a bit of a allocator junky and have commercial implementations under my belt back at symbian.  That said, I would hesitate to tread the same path these days.  Suggesting someone try and make their own allocator instead of use, say, jemalloc or tcmalloc is just bad advice imo.  Linear was not a valid criticism.  Anonymous mappings in mmap is not posix, but sure everyone likely does it.  Hmm less details about your recommendations.  My concern is ever suggesting anyone make their own malloc; its not a profitable general-purpose solution to anything.

Comment: @Will We can agree to disagree :-) I myself like to roll my own things (and I must admit I didn't know about `tcmalloc`).

Answer (score 2):

i think you should using memory pool . allocate all memory you need (if size is Fix) at the first time when your project started and let  the arrays the  memory that  they need from the first array you allocated .

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use object pools in servers and other such apps that are characterized by continual and frequent allocation and release of large numbers of a few sets of objects, (in servers - socket, buffer and buffer-collection classes).  The pools are queues, created at startup with an appropriate number of instances pushed on, (eg. my server - 24000 sockets, 48000 collections and an array of 7 pools of buffers of varying size/count).  Popping an object instance off a queue and pushing it back on is much quicker than new/delete, even if the pool queue has a lock because it is shared across the threads, (the smaller the lock span, the smaller the chance of contention).  My pooled-object class, (from which all the sockets etc. are inherited), has a private 'myPool' member, (loaded at startup), and a 'release()' method with no parameters & so any buffer is easily and correctly returned to its own pool.  There are issues:

1) Ctor and dtor are not called upon allocate/release & so allocated objects contain all the gunge left over from their last use.  This can occasionally be useful, (eg. re-useable socket objects), but generally means that care needs to be taken over, say, the initial state of booleans, value of int's etc.

2) A pool per thread has the greatest performance improvement potential - no locking required, but in systems where the loading on each thread is intermittent, ths can be an object waste.  I never seem to be able to get away with this, mainly because I use pooled objects for inter-thread comms and so release () has to be thread-safe anyway.

3) Elimination of 'false sharing' on shared pools can be awkward - each instance should be initially 'newed' so as to exclusively use up an integer number of cache pages.  At least this only has to be done once at startup.

4) If the system is to be resilient upon a pool running out, either more objects need to be allocated to add to the pool when needed, (the pool size is then creeping up), or a producer-consumer queue can be used so that threads block on the pool until objects are released, (P-C queues are slower because of the condvar/semaphore/whatever for waiting threads to block on, also threads that allocate before releasing can deadlock on an empty pool).

5) Monitoring of the pool levels during development is required so that object leakages and double-releases can be detected.  Code/data can be added to the objects/pools to detect such errors as they happen but this compromises performance.

Answer (score 1):

1st, do you really have to "new" that thing ? Why not use a local variable or a per-thread heap object.

2nd, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage if your development environment supports it...

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody mentioned it, I might also suggest trying to use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/); this means using `new(gc)` instead of `new`, `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` and don't bother about `free`-ing or `delete`-ing memory objects. A couple of years ago, I measured `GC_malloc` versus `malloc`, it was a bit slower (perhaps 25µs for `GC_malloc` versus 22µs for system `malloc`).

I have no idea of the performance of Boehm's GC in multi-threaded usage (but I do know it can be used in multi-threaded applications).

Boehm's GC has the advantage that you should not care about `free`-ing your data.