# Is there any better implementation than malloc/calloc for allocating memory in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

As malloc/calloc is the old implementation defined in stdlib for C . 
Is there any **better implementation that can replace malloc/calloc** ? 
Please don't answer any wrapper method on malloc/calloc method.
The new implementation to allocate memory in C should not call **malloc/calloc** rather than it should implement its own method .

Comment: There is no such quality as "better", there are only benchmarks.

Comment: Are you stuck in C or can you use C++, too? There you will have the keyord new. But be carefull if you mix malloc/free with new/delete. What kind of job should this method do? (e.g. is it possible to set a max size array, is the type already known...)

Comment: *malloc is the old implementation* Old and therefore broken, right?

Comment: You should understand that `malloc` is `C` standard and is implemented differently on each platform a `C` compiler is ported to, there are even multiple implementations on a single platform

Comment: You're complaining about an "implementation" but you haven't told us the platform, compiler, version or vendor.  And what exactly is wrong with the one you've got - it's speed, size, colour, or ...??

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... it's doing a syscall, and I'm pretty sure the OS is handling that quite efficiently. I strongly encourage to read how memory is allocated and managed by the linux kernel, it blew my mind when I did :) some of the most beautiful code I've ever seen. Quite interesting discussion btw http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=120514094126123&w=2

Comment: todda : As for memory leak detection we use wrapper on malloc and malloc doesn't implement exception handling as "new" does in C++. So focus on answering rather than giving vague comment.

Comment: @PraveenSrivastava My comment didn't say anything about memory leaks or exceptions. So ... focus on reading my comment?

Comment: @todda.speot.is After reading your comment only I have replied back . So focus on answering and not showing your other skills here.

Comment: @PraveenSrivastava I answered this question before you commented on it. *answered 22 mins ago todda.speot.is* vs. *Praveen Srivastava 13 mins ago*. And I haven't said anything about memory leaks or exceptions (do you mean signals? This is C). I want whatever you're smoking. Minus the impeded reading comprehension side effects.

Answer (score 10):

Unless your application is multithreaded you probably shouldn't bother. [This article suggests (for one platform, at least) that `malloc` performs quite competitively in a single threaded environment](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/multiproc/multiproc.html).

> So, which allocator should you use in your application? `malloc` on the Solaris OS was shown to be a strong choice for single-threaded code.
>
> [image: Note the first case]
>
> [image: Note the first case]

You'll be hard pressed to do better than `malloc` or its very similar functions. If you want better memory allocation you can wrap `malloc` or call the operating system memory allocation functions (but lose out on portability) and place your own allocation logic on top of chunks of memory.

If you *really* need a better memory allocator, try [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/):

> The Hoard memory allocator is a fast, scalable, and memory-efficient memory allocator for Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X, and Windows. Hoard is a drop-in replacement for malloc that can dramatically improve application performance, especially for multithreaded programs running on multiprocessors and multicore CPUs.
>
> [image: Benchmark]

Note that [it's not necessarily free](http://plasma.cs.umass.edu/emery/licensing-hoard). If you want a free one, try [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147298/multithreaded-memory-allocators-for-c-c).

Comment: mimalloc's benchmarks show hoard explodes in time with a lot of different workloads. As high as 13 times slower than tc, mi, and je malloc.

https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc

Answer (score 4):

[Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/) is a "drop-in replacement for `malloc()`", that aims to improve memory-allocation performance.

Also, [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/) is another "drop-in replacement", whose aim is to make memory allocation issues easier to debug.

Maybe either of those works for you. It's a bit hard to understand *why* you want to replace `malloc()`, since you don't give any reasons.

Comment: mimalloc's benchmarks show hoard explodes in time with a lot of different workloads. As high as 13 times slower than tc, mi, and je malloc. github.com/microsoft/mimalloc

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `calloc()` function? I've never used it, but some people had.

[calloc tutorial link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=588)

Comment: calloc is just malloc with zero-ing of the allocated memory

Comment: @Paul R. Yes, but that easily could be considered a "better implementation", given the lack of useful requirements in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in google showed me that there are no other C methods to allocate memory as effectively as malloc does (taking care of memory alignment etc). From what I saw its quite hard and nasty to try to create your own malloc-replacement too...

You could use `brk()` and `sbrk()` but they are not part of standard C and they only work ok on Unixy systems. `mmap()` is also worth a look but it looks like it haves the same drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

[nedmalloc](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/) can be used as a drip in replacement for CRT memory functions, it can also be injected into already compiled apps.

if you are using glibc, you shouldn't worry too much, its a *very* good allocator, based on [dlmalloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html), they only time you should really worry these days is multi-threaded allocation where contention is an issue, in which case you want nedmalloc, [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) or TBB malloc.